# Mysql select records that have a sum below a given amount

Tags: mysql

I am somewhat new to mysql and am running into a problem. I have two tables. One contains customer info and the second contains billing info. I need to sum the cost of all bills for every customer and then select only the customer info/billing info that have a sum of < 1000.

Here are the two tables I am working with

Customer Table

```
CustId  last_name  first_name  address       phone        email
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
C1      Johnson    Cathryn     123 This Wy.  555-555-5555 me@gmail.com
C2      Bova       Vanessa     234 This Wy.  555-555-1111 van@gmail.com
C3      Kuney      Albert      356 This Wy.  555-555-2222 Al@gmail.com
```

Billing Table

```
end_date    total_cost    billing_id    CustID    Rental_ID
-----------------------------------------------------------
2014-05-25  249.95        CR011         C1        R1
2014-07-30  49.99         CR012         C2        R2
2014-08-25  809.91        CR013         C3        R#
```

Create table statements for those two tables are:

```
create table customer
(
CustID varchar(10) not null,
last_name varchar(50) not null,
first_name varchar(50),
address varchar(50),
phone varchar(15),
email varchar(50),
constraint pk_CustID primary key (CustID)
);
```

And

```
create table billing
(
end_date date not null,
total_cost decimal(6,2) not null,
billing_id varchar(10) not null,
CustID varchar(10) not null,
Rental_ID varchar(10) not null,
constraint pk_billing_id primary key (billing_id),
constraint fk_CustID foreign key (CustID) references customer (CustID),
constraint fk_Rental_ID foreign key (Rental_ID) references rentals 
(Rental_ID));
```

The statement I am trying to use is this

```
select c.last_name, c.first_name, sum(b.total_cost) 'from customer c left 
join billing b on c.custid = b.custid 
where b.total_cost < 1000 
group by c.last_name, c.first_name 
order by c.last_name, c.first_name;
```

The problem I am having is it is still returning records that have a sum that is > than 1000. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because in your current query, you are summing items that individually have a `total_cost` < 1000 try something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM (

    select c.last_name, c.first_name, sum(b.total_cost) as tc
    from customer c left join billing b  
    on c.custid = b.custid
    group by c.last_name, c.first_name
    order by c.last_name, c.first_name ) AS A

WHERE tc < 1000
```

note that since you have not posted your tables, I am unable to test the above

Comment: Im getting an error when I try that ...

ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'name, c.first_name
order by c.last_name, c.first_name ) A

Where tc < 1000' at line 5

Comment: Ok, I updated my OP so that it has sample tables that are similar to what my tables are. My tables are just larger than that. I hope that is what you were looking for. I appreciate the help. Thank you

Comment: Ok there they are. There are other tables in the database which is obviously why there are other constraints in those tables but I dont think those other tables should even come into play here...???

Comment: Thanks. Helped me to figure out that I had forgotten the AS keyword. Please see the update

Comment: Where was AS forgotten? Or should I say where do I need to put it to make it work correctly?

Comment: Oops, sorry I hadn't hit the submit button :(  it should be  AS A WHERE ..

Comment: Awesome! Works like a charm. Really appreciate the help :)

Comment: Absolutely! Will do that from here on out :)

Comment: all the best with your project